# Get values from GitHub Actions and execute with Newman

Tags: github, github-actions, postman-newman

I have this JSON:

```json
{
  "test_case": [
    "config_shop_appId1",
    "config_shop_appId2_mobile",
  ],
  "testEnvironments": [
    "PRO"
  ],
  "include": [
    {
      "test_config": [
        {
          "test_case": "config_shop_appId1",
          "jiraTestPlan": 0,
          "pm_collection": "collections/Config_shop.postman_collection.json",
          "pm_environment": "environments/PRO.postman_environment.json",
          "pm_globals": "environments/PRO_GLOBALS.postman_globals.json",
          "folder": "appWeb",
          "iteration": "resources/config_shop_appId1.json"
        },
        {
          "test_case": "config_shop_appId2_mobile",
          "jiraTestPlan": 0,
          "pm_collection": "collections/Config_shop.postman_collection.json",
          "pm_environment": "environments/PRO.postman_environment.json",
          "pm_globals": "environments/PRO_GLOBALS.postman_globals.json",
          "folder": "appMobile",
          "iteration": "resources/config_shop_appId2_mobile.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I use this JSON for my matrix strategy. I want to loop it, running the collections with Newman. I've tried different approaches, but I haven't been able to solve the problem.

Another important thing is that I don't want you to download my project every time I execute an API. It would be perfect to use the same terminal to execute all collections sequentially.